# Java/Servlet error with calculation class

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

We've recently started to work with servlets and so far so good. We're able to make most work, yet we encounter an issue when attempting to calculate a price, see below

```
    public int retrievePrice(int type, int height, int width) throws Exception{
    this.type = type;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

    int sum = 0;
    try {

        DataAccessObject data = new DataAccessObject();

        int priceOfGlass = 300; // Price of glass per m2.
        int priceOfFrame = 0;

        int glassInSqMeters = height * width;
        int glassPrice = glassInSqMeters * priceOfGlass;

        priceOfFrame = data.retrievePrice(type);
        int framePrice = (priceOfFrame * height) + (priceOfFrame * width);

        sum = framePrice + glassPrice;
        return sum;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 45; // debugging
}
```

The RetrievePrice can be found here:

```
public class DataAccessObject  {

public int retrievePrice(int frameType) throws Exception{
    int price = 0;
    try{
        DBConnector con = new DBConnector();
        ResultSet res = con.doQuery("SELECT * FROM pricing WHERE type = "+frameType+"");
        if (res.next()) {
            price = res.getInt("price");
        }
    } catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return price;
}
```

}

It's producing the following errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at Glazier.DataAccessObject.retrievePrice(DataAccessObject.java:22)
at Calculations.retrievePrice(Calculations.java:37)
at Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:53)
```

We need to access the database and pull the price of the actual window type! Any clues?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver jar file missing from your project. Please add mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar in your system path

Comment: It looks like it is already added... http://imgur.com/iD9x28f

Comment: I think you are creating in web application. If so please add in WEB-INF/lib folder. You added in your ide module and during creating war that jar file not includes in war. Or you may include this file in your server lib folder.

Comment: We solved it! We added it to the web-inf! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks you @casper